# Discord Bot how get get sender

Tags: python, bots, discord, sender

I am making a bot for discord with Python and I am wanting a command where for e.g. someone types

```
User: !hello
Bot: Hello User#1234
```

I have looked all over the internet and have not been able to find it. I have tried a lot of things and none of them have worked

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Telling us you've tried everything doesn't exactly help if we don't know what this "everything" is.

Comment: What discord api are you using for python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using `discord.py`, check out this example scripts:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/reply.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

---

If you want to add more commands it would be better to use the `@*.command()` decorator, see [the other examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py) for that. Basically the decorator version for the example above **should** look like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    """Answers a !hello command"""
    msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `discord.py` libary a message has a author variable which you can acess with `message.author` this returns either a `User` of a `Member` object.
You can get the display name of these with `message.author.name`(this would return User) while `message.author` would return User#1234
Also the `discord.py` libary has a pretty good documentation [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).